# what percent of my investments can I take out annually if I want it to still grow after beating inflation and taxes annually?

Tags: investing, savings, retirement, interest, withdrawal

I'm interested in learning how much money one might have to save and invest if they are aiming to live purely off of the capital gains from their investments while still allowing their money to grow after accounting for the withdrawal and yearly inflation rate.

Comment: If I withdraw 2% of my money annually while my investments average a 6% return annually whereas the inflation averages 3% per year, does 6%-2%-3%=1% mean my money still grew by 1% each year?

Comment: Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/115576/how-safe-is-the-4-rule-if-u-s-returns-trend-towards-world-returns

Comment: @SimonSuh It depends on the tax treatment of capital gains and investment income in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Similar question answered here: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/94304/11768

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to approach this:

- Take money out of your investments by looking backwards. Look back and see what they returned in the last 12 months and factor in inflation, and then take everything above that. You  may have to pay taxes on any capital gains, so you will not be able to spend all of that money, unless you plan on paying all your taxes from other sources. Another consideration is that sometimes you can have taxable income from your investments even if you don't sell any shares. This is when you have to pay taxes on dividends.

Unless your money is invested in a way that guarantees a specific level of returns, there is no way to know  how your investments will do in the future. And remember even bank accounts may only guarantee their rates for a specific window of time, or in some cases they can even change tomorrow.

You also don't know what inflation will be going forward.

When you look backwards you may find that over the previous 12 months your investments didn't beat inflation, or that they lost value, and you will not be able to sell anything without making things even worse.

Comment: Looking at only a 12-month period seems a bit risky.  Also, if you've already retired planning to live off of your investments, it doesn't work: if your investments lost value, you "can't" take anything out, but of course you have to in order to live.  The idea you describe can make sense with different parameters (e.g., longer time horizon) but the question is asking how to decide ahead of time when you have "enough", not how to decide how much to take out one year at a time.

Answer (score 0):

That TOTALLY depends on what assets you have and what you make as profits. There is an old rule that if you are in a diversified stock portfolio you can take out yearly 4%, though I heard 3% is more like it, but that WILL eat your assets. If you on the other hand get like 10% return on deposit (and yes, this IS A THING, I actually get 12%) and inflation is 2% - make the math.

The general point is that you need to calculate how much you loose through inflation and tax on that one (yes, your portfolio must grow by inflation POST TAX). Then you can take out the rest and pay tax on that and that is what you can take out.

But it all depends a lot on WHICH CURRENCY and WHICH TAX LEVEL you talk about. See how you are not giving any locale indication or currency indication? And locale is where the tax comes in.